# Elasticsearch seemingly random scoring and matching

Tags: elasticsearch, scoring, booleanquery

I am using a `bool` search to match against multiple fields. The fields have been analyzed at index time with multiple filters but mainly use of `edge_ngram`.

The issue I'm having is that scoring seems to be up in the air. I would expect my search for `savvas` to match one of my `first_name` fields of `Savvas` first, but they are scored much later. For example a search for `savvas` returns in order of score:

```
First name | Last name       | Email
___________|_________________|________________________
------     | Sav---          | ---@sa-------------.com
-----s     | Sa----          | sa----------s@-----.com
Sa----     | ----            | sa---------@-------.com  
Sa----     | --------        | sa-------@---------.com
sa-        | -----           | sa----------@------.com
Sa--       | ----s-----s     | sa------s-----s@---.com
Sa----     | -----------     | sa-----@-----------.com
Savvas     | -------s        | ----------@--------.com
Savvas     | -------s        | --------@----------.com
Sa-        | ---s----S------ | sa------s-----@----.com
```

I have replaced characters other than edge n-grams of the search term in the fields with `-` and modified the lengths of email to protect identities.

Infact searching for `ssssssssssssssss` although it doesn't exist in my data returns items with the most number of `s` characters in them. Something which I wouldn't expect to happen as I am not doing any manual ngrams to my search.

The issue also appears when I attempt to search for a phone number, I match any emails containing the characters `78` when searching for `782` over phone numbers that have `782` as exact ngrams.

It seems that elasticsearch is also performing the ngrams on my search query and not just the field and comparing the two and somehow favouring shorter matches to greater.

Here is my query:

```
{
    'bool': {
        'should': [ // Any one of these matches will return a result
            {
                'match': {
                    'phone': {
                        'query': $searchString,
                        'fuzziness': '0',
                        'boost': 3 // If phone matches give it precedence
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                'match': {
                    'email': {
                        'query': $searchString,
                        'fuzziness': '0'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                'multi_match': {
                    'query': $searchString,
                    'type': 'cross_fields', // Match if any term is in any of the fields
                    'fields': ['name.first_name', 'name.last_name'],
                    'fuzziness': '0'
                }
            }
        ],
        'minimum_should_match': 1
    }
}
```

And the index settings to go with it (apologies for verbosity but I don't want to exclude anything that may be important):

```
{
    "settings":{
        "analysis":{
            "char_filter":{
                "trim":{
                    "type":"pattern_replace",
                    "pattern":"^\\s*(.*)\\s*$",
                    "replacement":"$1"
                },
                "tel_strip_chars":{
                    "type":"pattern_replace",
                    "pattern":"^(\\(\\d+\\))|^(\\+)|\\D",
                    "replacement":"$1$2"
                },
                "tel_uk_exit_coded":{
                    "type":"pattern_replace",
                    "pattern":"^00(\\d+)",
                    "replacement":"+$1"
                },
                "tel_parenthesized_country_code":{
                    "type":"pattern_replace",
                    "pattern":"^\\((\\d+)\\)(\\d+)",
                    "replacement":"+$1$2"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer":{
                "intl_tel_country_code": {
                    "type":"pattern",
                    "pattern":"\\+(9[976]\\d|8[987530]\\d|6[987]\\d|5[90]\\d|42\\d|3[875]\\d|2[98654321]\\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)(\\d{1,14})$",
                    "group":0
                }
            },
            "filter":{
                "autocomplete":{
                    "type":"edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram":1,
                    "max_gram":50
                },
                "autocomplete_tel":{
                    "type":"ngram",
                    "min_gram":3,
                    "max_gram":20
                },
                "email":{
                    "type":"pattern_capture",
                    "preserve_original":1,
                    "patterns":[
                        "([^@]+)",
                        "(\\p{L}+)",
                        "(\\d+)",
                        "@(.+)",
                        "([^-@]+)"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "analyzer":{
                "name":{
                    "type":"custom",
                    "tokenizer":"standard",
                    "filter":[
                        "trim",
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "autocomplete"
                    ]
                },
                "email":{
                    "type":"custom",
                    "tokenizer":"uax_url_email",
                    "filter":[
                        "trim",
                        "lowercase",
                        "email",
                        "unique",
                        "autocomplete"
                    ]
                },
                "phone":{
                    "type":"custom",
                    "tokenizer":"intl_tel_country_code",
                    "char_filter":[
                        "trim",
                        "tel_strip_chars",
                        "tel_uk_exit_coded",
                        "tel_parenthesized_country_code"
                    ],
                    "filter":[
                        "autocomplete_tel"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings":{
        "person":{
            "properties":{
                "address":{
                    "properties":{
                        "country":{
                            "type":"string",
                            "index_name":"country"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "timezone":{
                    "type":"string"
                },
                "name":{
                    "properties":{
                        "first_name":{
                            "type":"string",
                            "analyzer":"name"
                        },
                        "last_name":{
                            "type":"string",
                            "analyzer":"name"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "email":{
                    "type":"string",
                    "analyzer":"email"
                },
                "phone":{
                    "type":"string",
                    "analyzer":"phone"
                },
                "id":{
                    "type":"string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested the index settings using the Kopf plugin's analyser and it appears to create the correct tokens.

Ideally I would only match exactly against the tokens created by my index and prioritise a more precise match in one of my bool's should queries as opposed to prioritising multiple bool shoulds matching.

However I would be happy if atleast it matched exact tokens only. I can't use a `term` search as my search string itself needs to be tokenized, just without applying any ngrams to it.

**To sum up my requirements:**

- Score first by largest possible match in any single field.
- Then score by lowest offset of possible match in any single field.
- Then score by number of fields matched giving preference to lower offset matches

**--- Update: ---**

I am getting much better results using a `dis_max`, it seems to be successfully matching greater ngram matches over multiple ngram matches except for the `phone` field which is still hard to query. Here's the new query:

```
{
    'dis_max': {
        'tie_breaker': 0.0,
        'boost': 1.5,
        'queries': [ // Any one of these matches will return a result
            [
                'match': {
                    'phone': {
                        'query': $searchString,
                        'boost': 1.9
                    }
                }
            ],
            [
                'match': {
                    'email': {
                        'query': $searchString
                    }
                }
            ],
            [
                'multi_match': {
                    'query': $searchString,
                    'type': 'cross_fields', // Match if any term is in any of the fields
                    'fields': ['name.first_name', 'name.last_name'],
                    'tie_breaker': 0.1,
                    'boost': 1.5
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: probably you don't want to be using *autocomplete* i.e name analyzer on the search string ,only during indexing i.e mapping should be *"first_name":{
                            "type":"string",
                            "index_analyzer":"name"
                        }*,

Comment: @keety ah so 'analyzer' affects both but 'index_analyzer' only affects one... this seems like what I want.

Comment: @keety tried that thanks it removed all the incorrect matches and now matches the exact ngram. Now I just need to work out how to factor position into that and score `name.first_name` slightly over `name.last_name` in my `cross_fields` query. If you want to put it into an answer I will give you the upvoting you deserve.

Comment: one approach would be to provide field boosts in multi-match i have updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you don't want to be using autocomplete i.e name analyzer on the search string ,only during indexing i.e mapping should be:

```
"first_name": {
    "type":"string",
    "index_analyzer":"name"
}
```

Also to score matches on *first_name* higher than *last_name* in multi-match you could  provide a field level boost as follows :

Example: last_name matches is half as relevant as  first_name

```
{
    'dis_max': {
        'tie_breaker': 0.0,
        'boost': 1.5,
        'queries': [ // Any one of these matches will return a result
            [
                'match': {
                    'phone': {
                        'query': $searchString,
                        'boost': 1.9
                    }
                }
            ],
            [
                'match': {
                    'email': {
                        'query': $searchString
                    }
                }
            ],
            [
                'multi_match': {
                    'query': $searchString,
                    'type': 'cross_fields', // Match if any term is in any of the fields
                    'fields': ['name.first_name', 'name.last_name^0.5'],
                    'tie_breaker': 0.1,
                    'boost': 1.5
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I edited your question to include your other answer from the comments.